# Firestore Flutter Searching : query documents starts with or equals to a string

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I try to query documents which have field 'userName' starting with or equals to 'name', when I tap 'n', 'na', 'nam' or 'name' in field :

[image: get users by name]

But there is no conditions gave by the firebase firestore sdk which responds to the need.

I tried arrayContains (which works only with array) :

```
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection(Strings.usersCollection)
      .where(Strings.userModelName, arrayContains: 'name')
      .get();
```

and isEqualTo doesn't check if the String starts with some chars :

```
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .where('userName', isEqualTo: 'name')
            .get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use 'isGreaterThanOrEqualTo' combined with 'isLessThan' and char codes :

```
return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(Strings.usersCollection)
        .where('userName', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query, isLessThan: query.substring(0, query.length-1) + String.fromCharCode(query.codeUnitAt(query.length - 1) + 1))
        .get();
```